# understanding PATH variable export at the beginning of the bash script

Tags: bash

I have fairly often seen that PATH variable is exported at the beginning of the script. For example in `/etc/init.d/rc` script in Debian Wheezy:

```
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
export PATH
```

While I understand that this ensures that executables used in the script are started from correct directories, I don't fully understand which shells are affected by this `export` statement. For example here I start the script named `rc`(PID 6582; command is "/bin/sh /etc/init.d/rc") in `bash`(PID 3987):

```
init(1)-+-acpid(1926)
        |-sshd(2139)-+-sshd(2375)---bash(2448)---screen(3393)---screen(3394)-+-bash(3395)---vim(3974)
        |            |                                                       |-bash(3397)---pstree(6584)
        |            |                                                       `-bash(3987)---rc(6582)---sleep(6583)
```

Am I correct that this PATH export statement in `rc` script affects only the /bin/sh with PID 6582 because parent shells(bash with PID 3987 in my example) do not inherit variables from children? In addition, am I correct that all the commands executed in script `rc` are started under the /bin/sh with PID 6582 and thus use this `PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin` variable? If yes, then hasn't the simple PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin been enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment variables are inherited by all the processes run from the script. `PATH` in particular affects the behaviour of the C functions `execlp()` and `execvp()`, so all the processes launched by the `init.d` script that started `sshd` and their descendants are impacted, but only until the point where one of these descendants changes and exports it.

In particular, `bash(2448)` most probably changes it, as it is a login shell, to match the system's and the user's config, so all it descendans are impacted by this change.

Then when you run manually the `/etc/init.d/rc` script by hand, the change is inherited by the `sleep` command (but that one never tries to run anithing).

> If yes, then hasn't the simple PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin been enough?

If you mean just setting the variable instead of also exporting it, it depends on what the `rc` script runs. If it launches anything that tries to run commands with any of those functions, then no, only after exporting `PATH` it affects the children.

Comment: Thanks! So when I run manually the `/etc/init.d/rc` script, then all the commands started from the script, which use `execlp()` or `execvp()` C functions, use the `PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin`?

Comment: Yes, but only because the script overwrites the previous value of `PATH`. I didn't explain this very well, but those two C functions are the ones mostly used when some code wants to run other commands. `system()`, which is also much used, uses `/bin/sh`, which normally is a symlink to `bash`, `dash` or other possibilities. `bash`, for instance, does not use `exec*p()` directly, but certainly uses `PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

`PATH` should already be exported by the parent shell when the script run, so indeed, there is no need.

I can imagine corner cases where the shell which runs your script might not be properly initialized, such as for a startup script running very early in the boot process, but for regular userspace scripts, things should be set up the way you want them already.